# How to filter records from a merged dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a merged dataset-which now i need to filter.

The merged dataset looks like this

```
Flower   Id         city        Color   Flower_y   City_y   Color_y
Jasmine 1023LD     Hawai        White   Jasmine    Hawai    White
Jasmine 1023LD     Hawai        White   Jasmine    Hawai    Yellow
Jasmine 1023LD     Hawai        White   Jasmine    Hawai    Orange
Lily    2457MH     Washington   Purple  Lily       Washington Yellow
Lily    2457MH     Washington   Purple  Lily       Washington Orange
Lily    2457MH     Washington   Purple  Lily       Washington Red
```

I need to filter this and get the row where color and color_y doesnt match, If there is atleast one row where the colors match then the whole row shouldnt be returned.
In above example, none of the Jasmine rows should be returned, as 1 row matches between color and color_y.
But Lily row has to be returned, Result dataframe should look like this.

```
Flower   Id         city        Color
Lily    2457MH     Washington   Purple
```

How do I achieve this ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the resulting DataFrame exactly as in your question, to get only the first row from a group that should be kept, apply and return `None` if there is any matching, otherwise give back `head(1)`:

```py
df = df.groupby('Flower').apply(
    lambda g: None if g['Color'].eq(g['Color_y']).any() else g.head(1)
).reset_index(drop=True).filter(regex='.*(?<!_y)$')
```

df:

```
  Flower      Id        city   Color
0   Lily  2457MH  Washington  Purple
```

---

Edit: Explanation about [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

For a given frame, a series of Booleans can be generated in a variety of ways:

Given the first group as g:

```py
    Flower      Id   city  Color Flower_y City_y Color_y
0  Jasmine  1023LD  Hawai  White  Jasmine  Hawai   White
1  Jasmine  1023LD  Hawai  White  Jasmine  Hawai  Yellow
2  Jasmine  1023LD  Hawai  White  Jasmine  Hawai  Orange
```

```py
print(g['Color'].eq(g['Color_y']))
```

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Index 0 meets the condition so it is `True`. The other two do not so they are `False`. This gets resolved to a single variable through `any()`. Which is `True` if any in the series are `True`.

```py
print(g['Color'].eq(g['Color_y']).any())
```

```
True
```

Conditions can be combined in a variety of ways including & and |.

Checking if the colors match OR Color_y endswith 'e', for example:

```py
print((g['Color'].eq(g['Color_y']) | (g['Color_y'].str.endswith('e'))))
```

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

And like before, `any()` or `all()` can be used on the Boolean series to resolve it to a single Boolean value.

Comment: Thank you-if i want to add City also in the group by-how would i do it

Comment: `groupby(['Flower', 'City'])` ?

Comment: thank you - and one more question - can you please help me understand how does the above work? and can i add another field also as OR condition inside lamba expression if my df has one more ?

Comment: Thanks much- let me play with it and try to modify the if clause to include OR inside lamba - thank you again

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `filter`. Then filter the required `columns`.

```
df = df.groupby('Flower').filter(lambda x : not (any(x['Color'] == x['Color_y'])))
use_cols = [col for col in df.columns if not col.endswith('_y')]
df = df[use_cols].drop_duplicates()
```